# Discs in DVD Drive not being read

Tags: dvd

Does anyone have an experience with Ubuntu that is no longer reading discs in the DVD drive? 
This is my first time Ubuntu does not see the disc :| The disc is fine and works on my other Ubuntu computers.

The drive is there and powered. I can even type in `eject` in a terminal and the drive will open. Using the command: `sudo lshw -C disk`  I am able to see info about my drive too. Actually BOTH of my internal DVD drives cannot read discs anymore. If the output is not readable below, here is the info in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/GqqSCTPw

```
*-cdrom:0               
       description: DVD writer
       product: DVD_RW ND-3500AG
       vendor: _NEC
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom1
       logical name: /dev/cdrw1
       logical name: /dev/dvd1
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw1
       logical name: /dev/scd0
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 2.1B
       serial: [_NEC    DVD_RW ND-3500AG2.1B06022300BT-LIGGY
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-cdrom:1
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: CDDVDW SH-S222A
       vendor: TSSTcorp
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
           logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/scd1
       logical name: /dev/sr1
       version: SB01
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Comment: Can you mount the DVD manually from the command line, e.g. `sudo mount -t auto /dev/dvd /media/dvd` (making sure that `/media/dvd` already exists)? If so, this could be a problem with the desktop automounting configuration.

Comment: It would be odd if this was a hardware problem because both drives broke at the same time. But perhaps there is a problem with the motherboard. If you have a bootable linux (or windows) install CD it would be worth testing it you can still boot. Once you've eliminated hardware you can focus on the ubuntu config.

Comment: @IHeartUbuntu How did you solve this trouble?

Answer (score 9):

Adding a entry in /etc/fstab  may solve your issue, I was having issues using programs in wine that would not recognize my cdrom. In your case start by running:

```
sudo mkdir -v /media/cdrom0 ; sudo mkdir -v /media/cdrom1
```

This will create the future mount points for your cdrom drives. Then run this command which will edit in the proper lines in your fstab file:

```
 echo "# cdrom 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab  
 echo "/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/  auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab  
 echo "# cdrom 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab 
 echo "/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/ auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Then you will want to remount the file systems listed in fstab with this command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Pop in a cd or dvd to see it this corrected the issue. If it did solve the issue there is some problem with automount. This is only a workaround for a bigger problem.

Answer (score 7):

*Is it one specific DVD or all DVDs?*

If it's all DVDs: You should also check the [regionset](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) in terminal type, `sudo apt-get install regionset`
 and then `sudo regionset`. And make sure the region code of the drive matches your [region code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code). (This happened to me a couple of times randomly...)

If it's one specific DVD: Have you remembered to install [libdvdread4](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) (if it's an encrypted DVD)?

Comment: no, any dvd.. not necessarily a movie. in fact i cannot read cd's either. my guess is that there was an update that changed something, because i had to use the Ubuntu CD to install Ubuntu initially :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, though the difference is that I got an error message that said :

```
mount point /media/cdrom/ does not exist
```

So instead of directly applying what dginsd says, you might want to try making a directory according to what error message you get, if you do get one. Since mine showed the above, this is what I put in the command line and it solved the problem for me:

```
sudo mkdir -v /media/cdrom
```

And you're done. This did it for me. Make sure to do it according to your error message.

Comment: I'm a bit new to this space so please excuse me for making you gnash your teeth on seeing that the code line doesn't show up like its on the other answers and comments. Sorry in advance :)

Comment: To format something as code, indent it with 4 spaces in front. See the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is almost 10 years old now, however I found a solution for those here by Google. This solution does not use the terminal, just the "Drives" and "Files" applications. First open "Disks", then find your DVD or CD drive, then note the "Device" data (the /dev location) in my case it's "/dev/sr0". Now, if you open the file manager, then go the "+ Other Locations" tab, then open your computer root directory ("Computer"). You can go to the "dev" folder, open it, then find your drive file, again, in my case "sr0", right click, then "Open With Other Application", then "View All Applications", then find "Disk Image Mounter", click select. Now your drive should be mounted. I know this is not a long-term effective solution and that you can't write to the disk, however, it should work if you just need to read (at least on 20.04 LTS).

Answer (score 0):

According to this post -- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1950008

Ubuntu 11.10 can not read the drive is set to 'Slave'. Setting it to 'Master' solved the problem.

Quote:

> So I have solved this problem. Lots of searching etc led me to pull
>   the DVD / CD drive out of the system and have a look if it was set to
>   'Slave' or 'Master' via the pins on the rear of the player.
>
> The switch was set to 'Slave', i moved this across to 'Master'
>   replaced the drive in the PC hooking it up again to it's connections
>   and hey presto everything is fine ! Plays DVD's and audio CD's etc no
>   problem.

Comment: I read that thread ... I'm not convinced this is the issue here, and telling someone to start changing their hardware configuration should be a last resort.

Answer (score -3):

Type in:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && 
sudo apt-get --quiet update && 
sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && 
sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: You should really explain what these commands do. What are you recommending to install and why?

Comment: I'd never do something which allows quiet and unauthenticated install of something that has the word "keyring" in it