# Can't find my DVD drive in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mount, dvd, devices

I am completely new to Linux, due to some problems in my Windows I decided to give Linux a try. I am quite liking it accept for some minor issues.

The biggest of them is that I cannot find my DVD drive in Ubuntu.

After I insert the disk, the drive's green light flickers and then nothing. I don't get anything on my unity bar or desktop.

There is no folder inside my /dev folder which indicates a dvd drive. There is a cdrom folder in my root folder but nothing is there.

If you guys know what's wrong, I'd appreciate the help.

Am a complete newbie so don't expect me to know anything about Ubuntu, although I have spent lots of hours in last 2 days googling my issue so I have basic information...

Comment: Can you look at the [top answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47329/discs-in-dvd-drive-not-being-read) and see if it helps? It's not an exact duplicate but it is close.

Comment: Good da i dvd was fine until i did a partial upgrade. When I write the first command I get this message Resolving www.medibuntu.org (www.medibuntu.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.medibuntu.org'

Answer (score 3):

To be able to read Double Layer DVDs on Ubuntu 12.04, you need to install the libdvdcss2 package with these commands:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list
sudo apt-get --quiet update
sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring
sudo apt-get --quiet update
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

Comment: This is not necessary for reading dual-layer DVD media in  general. This is specifically necessary for reading/playing [most commercial video DVD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System). Such DVD's happen to usually be dual-layer (though they aren't always). Furthermore, it seems unlikely that this answer will help the original poster here, as even without `libdvdcss2`, you can usually still see whether or not a DVD is in the drive on an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install libdvd package that downloads and installs the required dependencies.

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

You need to config it. It will install dependencies automatically.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```