# Unable to play DVD or locate its contents

Tags: dvd

I have a DVD I want to watch but I can't find the disc drive in the OS. The drive itself turns on, spins up and then turns off.

I've checked media folders and have a "mydvd" and "usr" folder and nothing is in either one.

I could be missing missing drivers? I'm new to Ubuntu and this is my first big road block.

So far, I've tried 
`sudo lshw -class disk`
and all it shows is a usb drive and my hardrive.

Am I overlooking something obvious here?

Comment: Your optical drive will shop up in "Disks" (gnome-disk-utility) even if there is nothing in it.  If you don't see your optical drive, it may be broken or not connected.  If you see the device, but don't see a disk, it's likely the disc is damaged or otherwise unreadable.

Comment: fyi: the cd-dvd-drive spinning up doesn't tell you much; you can connect a power lead only to a drive; insert disk & get the same reaction (ie. no data cable connected to drive the drive at all, showing it's just the drive checking out of the disk will spin reliably & to send *disk-inserted* data to any connected machine.  If the disk/disc didn't spin reliably the drive itself can spit out the faulty-disk without the OS being told of insertion (*but this likely varies on make/age of devices*)

Comment: Sometimes it is just cheaper/easier to get a basic/cheap external PC DVD drive.  Try a known good DVD disc first.  Here is another question that might help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/155428/cant-find-my-dvd-drive-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1

Comment: What are the contents of said DVD? Is it a regular DVD-VIDEO or a DVD-ROM with software, media files or others?