# Can't mount data DVD using 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd

I cannot mount a data DVD using Ubuntu 12.04.

I *can* read the DVD using a different OS, so the DVD is not the problem.

I *can* read other CDs using Ubuntu.

The error I get is:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/dvd /cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

The relevant output from lshw is:

```
   *-cdrom
        description: DVD reader
        product: DVD/CDRW UJDA775
        vendor: MATSHITA
        physical id: 0.0.0
        bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
        logical name: /dev/cdrom
        logical name: /dev/cdrw
        logical name: /dev/dvd
        logical name: /dev/sr0
        version: CB03
        capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
        configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

I have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and run /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh.

Comment: When you say you can read the DVD on a different OS, do you mean in the same computer/drive?  Or on another computer?

Comment: Check out this thread
[Discs in DVD Drive not being read][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47329/discs-in-dvd-drive-not-being-read