# What should the correct path be for my CD/DVD drive in 12.04 and how do I change it?

Tags: 12.04, location

After a fresh install of 12.04 on a dell Inspiron 530 when right clicking on the CD/DVD drive and selecting properties it indicates for location:  "///" Obviously this drive does not work.

Whats the best fix for newb? Please don't go cryptic on me give me a long shot answer.

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I think the default device path for CD/DVD Drives is:   **/dev/sr0**

And when you have a CD/DVD in, you need to go to **/media/[userame]/[devicename]**

Comment: Whats the best fix for newb? Please don't go cryptic on me give me a long shot answer.

Comment: you need to view the contents of the CD/DVD or it doesn't list the drive at all?

Comment: Drive contents are not listed at all. the drive icon shows up under places then computer.  It appears as an icon next to an icon labeled  "file system" Clicking on the CD/DVD Drive with media in it, I've tried several difference media results in - nothing happening.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47329/discs-in-dvd-drive-not-being-read

take a look at the first answers and see if you can relate.

Comment: "And when you have a CD/DVD in, you need to go to /media/[userame]/[devicename]"  may indeed be where I need to go yet the question remains: How do I get there?

Comment: open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T,
type in `cd /media/[username]/`

then type `ls` and see if there is any folder there. If yes, type `cd [foldername]` and you will be in the drive.

Comment: I entered :~$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/dvd /media/dvd
and got this response: 
mount: mount point /media/dvd does not exist   How do I alter the drive path from /// to "/dev/sr0"  much thanks

Comment: cd /media/[username]/ yeilds:  No such file or directory

Comment: les@TheDeviceofLes:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
[sudo] password for les: 
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
    
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD writer
       product: DVD+-RW GSA-H73N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: B103
       serial: [
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
les@TheDeviceofLes:~$