# How to reverse these settings?

Tags: mount, sudo, dvd, mountpoint

I followed the first answer give by user "dginsd" from here

[Discs in DVD Drive not being read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47329/discs-in-dvd-drive-not-being-read)

because I couldnt mount a game I had on a DVD disk and thought that ubuntu wasnt seeing my DVDrom drive in general...

turns out that the DVD is just not readable and now everytime I put a cd or DVD on that drive ubuntu looks at it as a music disk.... and I think its because of the commands I entered...

how can I reverse this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the issue you describe is caused by those entries, but here is how to revert them:

Open a terminal and type the following command:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit /etc/fstab
```

(best copy the command and paste it into the command line by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). You will be asked for your password.

This will open the file `/etc/fstab` in a text editor.

#### Be very careful in the editor, you are running it as root

At the end of the file you will find the following lines

```
#cdrom 0
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/ auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0

#cdrom 1
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/ auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

insert a `#` at the beginning of the two lines starting with `/dev/sr0`, the save the file.

#### Explanation of the command line

- `pkexec` invokes the commadnd `gedit /etc/fstab` with *root* permissions (like `sudo` would do, but for a GUI-program)
- `env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY` send the current values for `DISPLAY` (usually `:0`) and `XAUTHORITY` into the respective Environment variables for `pkexec`, thus preventing a permission problem because the display to use does not belong to *root*

  ### (see [How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec))

You should **not** use `sudo` to invoke a GUI-program, that might cause the inability to log into your Desktop.