# Problem with opening cd tray

Tags: drivers, dvd, cd, eject

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T400. I  have had a problem with my cd tray for two years.

Today I pressed the button on the cd tray, and inserted a cd into the cd tray, and then I opened and read the content of the cd in Nautilus. Then I pressed again the button of the cd tray, and removed the cd from the tray, without closing the Nautilus window that opens the the cd's content. Later I closed the Nautilus window.

Now I try to press the button on the cd tray to insert a second cd into the tray, but the tray doesn't open. I also try the command line, and there seem to be some problem:

```
$ eject
$ eject -T
eject: CD-ROM tray close command failed: Input/output error
$ eject -t
eject: CD-ROM tray close command failed: Input/output error
```

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

---

**Update:**

I used a paper clip to open the cd tray, and insert the second cd in, but after a minute, it begins to try to read the cd by making sound and flashing the light, but the cd still isn't mounted.

I guess it might not (just) be a hardware problem? Can the driver module for the cd tray be the problem? How can I test that, and make the driver module work?

---

I am following [Discs in DVD Drive not being read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47329/discs-in-dvd-drive-not-being-read). Here is the output of `lshw` for the cd tray/drive:

```
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GSA-U20N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: HX12
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
```

I fail to mount the cd manually:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/t/cdrom
$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/cdrom /media/t/cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

Comment: Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: I can't reboot right now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a paper clip? Many CD drives, particularly older models, have a small hole into which you can insert the end of a paper clip and force the tray open.

Comment: thanks. where can i insert a paper clip into?

Comment: Mostly there is a tiny hole in the frontside in the tray or below.

Comment: can you show me in a picture? @Videonauth

Comment: can I do it without turning off my laptop? @Videonauth

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/agaV9.jpg) like this and yes you should be able to do this without turning off the laptop.