# DVD Drive can read CDs but no DVDs

Tags: drivers, dvd, cd

I'm having a weird issue here. The DVD-Drive is recognized and regular CDs are readable, but DVDs (talking about the regular burned one, not movies) aren't.

`sudo lshw -C disk` outputs (except for the hd):

```
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVD-RAM UJ890AS
       vendor: MATSHITA
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

I did some checks but that device seems to be perfectly supported by the system. No external drivers needed. Some [posts suggested editing fstab](https://askubuntu.com/a/221535/363916) but the drive is found and regular CDs work. (In fstab are only the hdd and its swap partition registered).
`libdvdread4` is installed too.